# How to set image on Texture in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I am new to Unity 3D and I want to do just little task: to set image on a `Texture` instance in Unity 3D. I don't know how to do this at runtime, and I also would like to know how I set its transparency low.

I don't need Texture2D - I just need Texture. My image is in `.png` format. I also want set an image from my documents directory on to this texture.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- First import your image into your project by simply dropping it in your project window.
- Select the image once it's in the project window and make sure that it is set to a Texture Type of Texture in your inspector.
- Next, create a new material by right clicking in your project window.
- Next you want to assign your image to this material and you can go about doing this by dragging and dropping your image (which is in the project window) on to your newly created material. In recent versions of Unity, you will need to drop it on the square to the left of "Albedo".
- Then click on the new material and in your inspector window it should show you that your image is the active texture and the shader should be set to diffuse by default.
- To activate transparency you'll want to change the shader type by clicking on the shader drop down menu in the inspector window and selecting Transparent/Diffuse (or any of the transparency options depending on what look you're going for).
- After this to change it's transparency, simply click on the main color swatch and there should be a new window that opens giving you all kinds of modifiers (with 4 horizontal sliders to adjust Red, Green, Blue & Alpha).
- Adjust the Alpha slider to affect the transparency of your material.

Now, whenever you need to make a call to your material at runtime (e.g if you wanted to change the texture applied to a gameobject), simply do so by using:

```
renderer.material
```

This will affect the material off the gameObject that the script is attached to. So for example, if you wanted to [**change the texture**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material-mainTexture.html) at runtime from script you could say:

```
// Assign the texture exposed in the inspector the renderer's material

var texture : Texture;
renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
```

And if you wanted to change the alpha channel:

```
renderer.material.color.a = 0 // For example
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: Thanks for detail answering but if i want to change image at run time  on texture, so how can i do this?

Comment: You need to change the material. `renderer.material = newMaterial`. For example you can set `var newMaterial : Material` as a public variable and than choose the Material in the Inspector which he should use.

Comment: Step 3 `Next, create a new material by right clicking in your project window.` really needs a better description on how to do this.

Comment: Dragging an image on a material doesn't work.  I get the "circle with line through it" icon.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that these instructions are quite out of date, and no longer apply in 2019.4.[Importing textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ImportingTextures.html) and [Creating and using materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html) covers this.
You need to set the Shader to `Unlit/texture`

Comment: This answer could use some updating, incorporating the below answer by Tiago

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the image in your Assets

1. Create a new Material.
2. Change the shader of the Material to "Unlit/Texture". You'll get the following

[image: New Material ready for texture]

3. Drag the image to where it says "None (Texture)" or click the select button and select the image. Then you'll get the texture

[image: Final texture]

Answer (score 1):

At first you to need to import an image to your `asset` folder.

Use below given code if you want to set image on a `Texture` runtime using code

```
[SerializeField] private Texture _texture;
[SerializeField] private GameObject _gameObject;


void Start()
{
    Material m = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
    m.color = new Color(1,1,1,.5f);
    m.mainTexture = _texture;
}
```

First of all assign a `Gameobject` that you want to change texture.
Then assign an image in `_texture`.

then get a `material` from that object and `assign` a `_texture` to that `material.mainTexture`.